# Order of answers

Tags: support, answer-order

How is the ordering of answers done?

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582555/always-show-browser-scrollbar-to-prevent-page-jumping) question, there are 2 answers as I am writing this question. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12582621/842386) having 40 votes is not on the top instead another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12582662/842386) having less votes.

How is the ordering of answers done?

Comment: How have you ordered them? There are three options (Active, Oldest, Votes). From trying the three, it looks like you have clicked on Active.

Comment: Yes, the 11 vote answer is more active by an entire 35 seconds :D

Comment: Great, how do you know of 35 seconds?

Comment: If you hover over any date/time on the site, you'll get the exact Zulu time it was posted. The most recent edit of the first answer occurred at xx:07:55 and the other answer was posted 35 seconds later at xx:08:30. or something like that.

Comment: ok, is it(active) as simple as comparing the time at which answers were posted? OR it includes other parameters like comments?

Comment: It includes edits to the answer yet not comments. (You can see the last time those happened from the time in the middle of the post, if there are any.)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Click one of the other tabs to see a different sorting.

You probably want votes.

Note that a lower voted answer can still appear on top if the answer is accepted. An accepted answer is always the top one* - it's like a pinned tweet.

---

<sup>*A self-accepted answer is not pinned to the top</sup>

Comment: "An accepted answer is always the top one" unless it's a self-accept, which is not pinned